# SSIS error 'object not exist'while executing the package

Tags: ssis

I have created some packages which is take the data from the sql server and load the data into the excel files.i have mapped the excel sheets dynamically.sometimes my packages work fine without any error but some times it gives error that "Object is not exist".i have set the expression for excel connection manager with excel file path property,but sometimes still getting error.please help me on this to sort out this problem.thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

If you're setting ConnectionString in Connection Manager as expression, you also need to set DelayValidation property of Connection Manager to True, if the files that ConnectionString references will be created during execution of the package.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for ur quick help on this,you saved me..:)

Comment: Hi,please help it worked fine for first time but after that again got same error.please help on this.

Comment: Ok, but what has changed since then?

Comment: nothing changed,i have set the delay validation property set to True in each connection manager,and run the package it worked fine for after setting the property,and then again i ran the package it thrown the same error.

Comment: Set this property on data flow tasks, too.

Comment: This is the expression which i have given in excel connection manager in the file path:----@[User::ExcelDestPath]+ @[User::IRT_50K_ALL_Sites_ICN_FileName]+ @[User::CurrentDate] C:\Users\gsing61\Desktop\ExcelFileDestination\IRT Daily Scorecard_50K_ALL_Sites_ICN list_5.20.2013.xlsx

Comment: It seems that the path is indeed invalid. Where did you get this path (C:\...) from? Is this true location of you file, did you copy this from a variable, or from connection manager?
Run your package again, and when it derails, debug the package and check all the variables you posted, and the entire expression. I'm pretty sure it'll point to nonexistend file.

Comment: Hi Frik,i have tried with that but still getting same error,dont know what i have to do.very soon this package is gng to live in production.please help me on this...just want add one thing,yesterday i ran this package it worked fine without any error,but today again gae same error..thanks in advance..